# Trigger a SharePoint Online Action from another Application

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have a use case where I would like to create a button in another application, that when clicked, will trigger a Flow or something, that will lead to the creation of a Folder in a specific document library in SharePoint.

Could such a use case be achieved with SharePoint Online and/or Flow?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTTP Trigger for Flow that allows your application to trigger your flow using that address.

But, if you just want to create a folder in SharePoint from your application then CSOM is your friend. If your app is .NET then you can add PnP Core via NuGet and creating a folder should be pretty easy: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline

You can make similar calls via REST as well: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

Comment: Can you point me to any resources on how I can wire up the button on the target application? e.g. is it simply a matter of an anchor tag that has href="flow request url"?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a PowerApp and add button within it which will run the Microsoft Flow. (You can also embed the PowerApp within SharePoint page if you want).

You can create a new folder using `Send an HTTP request to SharePoint` in Microsoft Flow.

Below articles will help you to start with this:

**References**:

1. [Start a flow in a canvas app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/using-logic-flows).
2. [Microsoft Flow – Create a Folder in a document library using Microsoft Flow](https://veenstra.me.uk/2018/08/09/microsoft-flow-create-a-folder-in-a-document-library-using-microsoft-flow/amp/).
3. [Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest).
4. [Use the PowerApps web part in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-powerapps-web-part-6285f05e-e441-408a-99d7-aa688195cd1c).

Comment: I want to add the Button to trigger in an action from **another** application (not inside Flow or a SharePoint page).

Comment: May I know which application particularly you are trying to build?

Comment: It is another website, a custom website, and I want to add a HTML or JS button there - that when clicked - will trigger the flow which then goes off and creates a folder structure in SharePoint Online.